# Displaying a message with a website address upon first install of Android app

Tags: android, hyperlink, apk

This may be a noob question in Android porgramming but here goes..

I have an apk setup on my website as a link to say www.manusandme.com/test.apk. I would like to capture this website address on which the link is and display it to the user once the app is installed and opened for the first time.

Say once the user installs app and opens it for the first time, on the home screen it displays. Hi, you just got this app from www.manusandme.com. instead of say Hello World!

User goes to site ----> Clicks on link ---> APK is downloaded to phone ---> User installs it ---> THen user opens it ----> Message with website on which user clicked needs to be displayed on home screen.

Is this possible in android? Kindly advise.

Thanks in advance for your help.

With regards,
Manus

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can save in you SharedPreferences some flag informing that this message was already shown. For example in you main activity do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean wasShown = preferences.getBoolean(Const.Config.MESSAGE_WAS_SHOWN, false);
```

then if wasShown is false, then show your message and after showing it update this preference to true.

Comment: Thanks marcin. But is it possible to pass the website address to your android app when the user clicks on it?

Comment: Yes, you can intercept when user clicks on your app in browser, but only once your app is installed (using `<intent-filter>`), and its not what you want? Maybe you could create special apk for downloading from website, it would show this message?

Comment: Hi marcin. I have added a typical flow of events that I am expecting. Could you lend me some more explanation on how this will work?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, if you can live with special apk compiled for your www installations, then simply add this message with sharedpreference checking.

Comment: Hi marcin, thanks for the reply. COuld you explain further about the special apk for downloading from website? Is it a new app just for donwloading and installing the app?

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes its possible to pass the website url with the parameter attached with its url. 
for example :www.your_url.com/Firsttimeapp/IMEI_no=122412342355345

And create a separate catching on the website that only add's the New IMEI no of the mobile.

The Problem with the shared preference will that once any clear's the app data it will again send an entry on the server side.

Comment: Hi Balu, thank you for the answer. I am a bit confused now. I think I will edit the post so that the intention of the post is a bit more clear.

Comment: Hi Balu, I have added a typical flow of events to the OP. Kindly share more information oh how this works.